# Is there any way to get unique elements in list when realizing ManyToMany association?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, collections

I have **`Language`** entity. And I want to realize `ManyToMany` association with the same table. `translation_ways` table have just two fields `fromLangId int(3)` and `toLangId int(3)`.

```
@Entity(name = "Language")
@Table(name = "language")
public class Language implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "language_id")
    private int id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "short_name", unique = true, length = 2, nullable = false)
    private String shortName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "full_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "translation_ways",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fromLangId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "toLangId"))
    private Set<Language> toLangs;

    //getters and setters here
    //ovverrided equals() & hashCode()
}
```

What I want to do is to get the list of all Languages (with Set of the Languages entities joined by `translation_ways` table). The problem is that `Criteria.list()` returns list with duplicates. Amount of duplicates in the list is equal to how many times current id appears in the `translation_ways.fromLangId` column. In my case it is redundant information and I want to get list of unique Objects.

So the first question is if there is the some recommended or best of the best way to get this list without redundant elements? Convert returned `ArrayList` to `LinkedHashSet`? Or maybe I just did something wrong with my `Criteria`???

Also, have one more related question. If I'll call this query in the second time hibernate will take data from a cache, am I right?

I will appreciate any recommendations, ideas, links and help. Thanks everyone in advance.

**my request:**

```
Criteria c = this.template.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Language.class);
    c.setCacheable(true)
        .setCacheMode(CacheMode.NORMAL)
        .setCacheRegion("staticLangList");
List<Language> ls = c.list();
return ls;
```

**P.S.** Hibernate version is 5.0.1.Final.

Answer (score 0):

use `setResultTransformer` in `Criteria` to avoid duplicates.

```
c.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine for me.
Can you also tell me if I am right about a cache? As I understood I need query cache for this case (I have exactly the same request which will be called for many times) and then, it will take data from cache in the next time, without request to the db????